# 2 LAN both connected to internet: how can I choose which one to use in my browser?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

I have a WIFI and a LAN both connected to internet (with 2 different provider).

How can I set my browser to use 1 instead of the other to browser?

Comment: Under which OS?

Comment: I've never used multiple connections myself before, but under Windows would setting the priority of a connection higher/lower (under Nextwork Connections) affect this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not normally done on a per-browser basis, but rather is done system-wide using routing metrics:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrics_(networking)

The route with the lower metric for a given connection will be chosen.  Windows by default will set a LAN connection to have a lower metric than a wireless connection, but there are things that can cause this to change over time.  You can set the metric for a given route using the command line program aptly named `route`.